# how to find stored procedure without knowing Database name

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

can anyone tell me how to find code of stored procedure?
I don't know the database name even so how could I find that.
Please help me with this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find stored procedure by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574244/find-stored-procedure-by-name)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to search for the SP in all Databases.

```
DECLARE @SPROCS AS TABLE (DBNAME VARCHAR(64), SCHEMANAME VARCHAR (128), 
STOREDPROCNAME VARCHAR(128), 
TYPE VARCHAR(10), TYPE_DESC VARCHAR(128), 
CREATE_DATE DATETIME, MODIFY_DATE DATETIME, IS_MS_SHIPPED INT)
INSERT INTO @SPROCS
EXECUTE SP_MSFOREACHDB N'USE ?; SELECT ''?'', 
S.NAME AS SCHEMANAME, O.NAME AS STOREDPROCNAME, 
TYPE, TYPE_DESC, CREATE_DATE, MODIFY_DATE, IS_MS_SHIPPED
FROM SYS.ALL_OBJECTS AS O INNER JOIN SYS.SCHEMAS AS S 
ON S.SCHEMA_ID = O.SCHEMA_ID 
WHERE O.TYPE IN (''P'',''V'',''PC'',''FN'',''TF'',''U'')
AND IS_MS_SHIPPED = 0'

SELECT * FROM @SPROCS
WHERE DBNAME NOT IN ('MASTER', 'TEMPDB', 'MODEL', 'MSDB', 'DBA') AND STOREDPROCNAME LIKE '%<SP Name>%'
ORDER BY DBNAME, SCHEMANAME, TYPE, STOREDPROCNAME
```

### Option 2

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 
'if exists(select 1 from [?].sys.objects where name=''<SPname>'')
select ''?'' as FoundInDb from [?].sys.objects where name=''<SPname>'''
```

### Option 3

Or if possible you can install a tool from `RedGate SQLSearch` to do it easily

Comment: it's so complicated. Just give me one statement to do so.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM dbo.sysobjects
WHERE type = 'P'